# What is the recommended way to handle changes in local web storage from upstream?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

The question is about the general approach. For me, I try to present the problem using AngularJS with [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage).

Let's say I have something like this saved in local storage:

```
$scope.$storage = $localStorage;
$scope.$storage.food = { type: 'candy', eaten: false }
```

With this way, I've saved this in local storage. So next time a user visit my page, I know if he/she has eaten the candy. However, in the future, I change my app and change the structure of **food**.

So how should I update this? Two things must be took care of are:

1. Notify client of new structure for storing.
2. Integrate that change with the old storage.

My approach is using a version field to indicate changes, and upon seeing that, reset all clients storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This process is called "data migration" (i.e. upgrading a data structure as the application evolves). It's a well-known problem from the database world (and before that for config/preferences files).

The usual approach is to add a version in the header of the data structure. That means the header is always the same (or just changes in backwards-compatible ways) while the payload (the actual data) can change as much as it needs.

A simple solution just checks the version and uses defaults when the version doesn't match. More elaborate schemes contain migration code which can upgrade a data structure from version `N` to `N+1`. Control code will then apply all the migration steps necessary to upgrade all data structures to the latest version.